# ASP.Net Core 3.1 MVC Error while using stored procedures

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

The client wants all communication with the database to be done through stored procedures. To do this in ASP I am using FromSqlRaw like so:

```
_context.Visit.FromSqlRaw("exec VisitApi_RecordVisit @User", userParam)
```

The stored procedure does its job and the visits are recorded. However every time it triggers an error is thrown in the console:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The required column 'Id' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.
```

While researching this error I found that this error is because the table it is recording to has a primary key. To fix this problem I would have to drop the primary key column and then add it back with the "Identity Specification" set to "No". I have also tried adding .HasNoKey(); to the table and tried to update the database. However, when I do it tells me I need to drop the column and add it back again. The problem is that there is already ~200,000 visits already recorded and I don't want to lose the Ids that are already tied to each row. Is there any way for me to get rid of this error without dropping the column and or deleting existing data?

Comment: Why Entity.FromSqlRaw() was choosen to run an arbitrary Sql proc?

Comment: Use context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC AddCategory @CategoryName", name);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could alternatively use:

```
using(var context = new SampleContext())
{
    var name = new SqlParameter("@CategoryName", "Test");
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC AddCategory @CategoryName", name);
}
```

(taken from https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql#database.executesqlcommand)

Documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.database?view=efcore-3.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlcommand?view=efcore-3.1

Comment: What would 'new SampleContext()' be in this case?

Comment: Your DbContext. If it's already created / taken from DI, you don't need to create it again.